# RoR - Fetch blog feed based on requesting domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, multiple-domains, dynamic-url

I have a Rails application that runs on two domains, `domain1` and `domain2`. Each domain has its own associated blog, `domain1blog` and `domain2blog`, respectively. Currently, I have a model that fetches one of the blogs:

```
require 'rss'
require 'open-uri'

class Blog

BLOG_URL = 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/domain1blog?format=xml'
POST_LIMIT = 2

def self.fetch_entries
  Rails.cache.fetch('blog', expires_in: 10.minutes) do
    posts = []

    begin
      open BLOG_URL do |rss|
        feed = RSS::Parser.parse(rss)
        posts = feed.items.slice 0...POST_LIMIT
      end
    rescue OpenURI::HTTPError
    # Ignore silently.
    end

    posts
  end
end

end
```

Right now, this model fetches content from `domain1blog` irrespective of the the domain from which the call is made.

How can I set the `BLOG_URL` so that it points to `domain1blog` from `domain1` and `domain2blog` from `domain2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can

- Either create `Blog` entities with a (predefined) `url` field in your database, meaning that your `fetch_entries` method will work out of the box (as an instance method though)
- or extract the domain in the controller, using [`ActionDispatch::Http::URL.domain`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionDispatch/Http/URL/domain)